# displaying image field in gridview

Tags: vb.net

I've made a database with Access and I've made a form with vb .I want to display one of my tables in grid view in my form, but the grid view does not show my image field.I've used Attachment type for my image field in access. I have tested OLE object type too but it doesn't work.
what should I do?help me please .

Comment: well, what type is the image col in the DB?  And how did you store it?

Comment: it's type is attachment,in access we can easily store the image by browse the image path and then it becomes the part of the project, I think.